# Folder icon choice

Tags: windows-7

The "classic" folder icon is a horizontal manila folder but the new folder icons are vertical folders which look like an open book.  Is there any way to change the folder icons to the classic style in Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

1. Right click on the folder
2. You will get folder properties
3. Click on the tab `"Customize"`
4. Click on `"Change Icon.."` button
5. It will show the Icons list, which is point to `"%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll"`
6. Select the icon
7. Click `OK` button
8. Click `OK` button once again
9. Now you will see Icon changed

If you are looking for changing to classic icons for all folders in one shot then it seems there is no option to do.

Refer **[How to view classic folder display/icons in Windows 7?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-to-view-classic-folder-displayicons-in-windows/b774f534-0fc2-46a3-a9d4-e3791a47116d)** for more info.

Comment: This works for great if you only have a few folders you want to change. I think Folderoll's intent is to change the icons system-wide.

Comment: @iglvzx: I have updated my answer with more info.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this tutorial.  I just tried this on my Windows 7 x64 machine, and the folder icons got changed after i logged off and back in.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/23825-folder-icon-change-windows-7-default-folder-icon.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! We generally prefer you dont just post a link, and give us a little summary, if possible. thanks!